# UIImage Does Not Load Image

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage

I am using UIImage to plot a png. I have getting a weird behavior that I cannot understand.

The following piece of code results in a nil im reference and thus prints "PROBLEM!"

```
UIImage *im = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"tree.png"]; 

if (nil==im)
    NSLog(@"PROBLEM! IMAGE NOT LOADED\n");
else
    NSLog(@"OK - IMAGE LOADED\n");
```

This piece of code works finely:

```
UIImage *im = [UIImage alloc]; 

[im initWithContentsOfFile:@"tree.png"];

if (nil==im)
    NSLog(@"PROBLEM! IMAGE NOT LOADED\n");
else
    NSLog(@"OK - IMAGE LOADED\n");
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8):

`[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"tree.png"];` will return to you image if image `/tree.png` exist. But it doesn't exist. You should pass to `initWithContentsOfFile` full path, not only name of file.

Now, second one code works because of `[UIImage alloc]` return some reference that is not initialized. In next line your are trying to init it with `[im initWithContentsOfFile:@"tree.png"];` but you've forgotten to save returned value in `im`, like this: `im = [im initWithContentsOfFile:@"tree.png"];`.

If image `tree.png` is saved in your bundle, then you can use such approach : `UIImage *im = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.png"];` or such:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tree" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *im = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Answer (score 4):

Is the image in your bundle and is it a PNG image? The UIImage Documentation mentions the following when using `initWithContentsOfFile:`

> An initialized UIImage object, or nil if the method could not find the file or initialize the image from its contents.

Also, since you are using the UIImage locally I assume from your code, you could just use the `imageNamed:` class method like so and it will search for the image in your main bundle:

```
UIImage *im = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tree.png"];

if (nil==im)
    NSLog(@"PROBLEM! IMAGE NOT LOADED\n");
else
    NSLog(@"OK - IMAGE LOADED\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tree" withExtension:@"png"];
UIImage *im = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

to load the image from your application bundle.

Comment: the answer was unanswered when I wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, your second piece of code is potentially dangerous. Actually `initWithContentsOfFile:` calls `autorelease` for the object, if file is not found. And if you tried to access image after a while, it would be an error (EXC_BAD_ACCESS).

So that you should always use `init` methods in pair with `alloc` and do not forget to `release` is somewhere.